# Running Remote Root Scripts on Fedora

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, command-line, fedora

I'd like to automate root scripting actions on my remote Fedora server via SSH without having to install the scripts on the server. To do this, I'm trying to use Bash's inline script notation. This works fine in Ubuntu, but I'm getting strange errors on Fedora.

e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -t myuser@myserver <<EOI

su -
ls /root
exit

exit
EOI
```

This gives me the output:

```
standard in must be a tty
ls: cannot open directory /root: Permission denied
```

I've also tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -t myuser@myserver <<EOI

sudo ls /root

exit
EOI
```

but this gives me:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

If I manually ssh in and run these commands, they run fine since myuser is in the sudoers file. I've Googled these errors and have tried some fixes, but nothing's worked so far. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're being prompted for the password but have no way to enter it. Here's a few things that should help.

Try an extra -t option: `ssh -tt myuser@myserver <<EOI`

Also this is a handy trick to log on as root without the root password being enabled: `sudo su -`

As a last resort you can setup your user to sudo without a password using `visudo`. You might see some comments like these to help you out:

```
# Uncomment to allow members of group sudo to not need a password
# (Note that later entries override this, so you might need to move
# it further down)
# %sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: I already tried the -tt trick. It doesn't work. It does cause me to be prompted for my password, but my password's in plaintext. Even if I type it in, nothing happens when I press enter.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized it only worked for me since I had recently sudoed on the target box so I didn't actually have to type in the password.

Comment: Setting my user to nopasswd in sudoers did the trick. My only concern are the possible security implications.

Comment: I agree, it does feel a little weird, especially if you are allowing public key authentication. Then someone would only need the key file to have remote root on the target box. It might be a good idea to disable key authentication in SSH.